# Finding Alternate Comparator by Pinout?

Tags: components, comparator

I am using the [TS391IYLT](https://www.digikey.com/product-detail/en/stmicroelectronics/TS391IYLT/497-10245-1-ND/2193322) in a design, but need to swap it with an alternate that has rail-to-rail capabilities. The issue I'm running into is that the pinout is somewhat irregular; see below. Most comparators I've found have a similar pinout, but IN- and IN+ are reversed.

Is there any way to search for parts by pinout? Such that the results only show chips with the same pinout?
[image: TS391IYLT pinout]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is common that if one manufacturer makes opamps with one particular pinning that that same manufacturer will tend to use that for many of their proprietary parts. So I suspect that you would have best luck searching through data sheets for the parts from the same manufacturer.

Second source type parts will of course not be like this and would follow the pinning used by the rest of the industry. This can be one strong incentive to use more generic parts.

As you do your search if you find that 95% of the op-amps that are in SOT23-5 packages all have this pinning:

1. OUT
2. VCC-
3. IN+
4. IN-
5. VCC+

Then there is a strong incentive for you to consider changing your design to accommodate the above pinning.

SOT23-5 packages are small but since just the IN+ and IN- appear to be swapped between your part and other common op-amps I would recommend performing etch-cut and hay wires rework to a couple of boards for testing and then move forward to change your artwork to use a part with the more common pinning.

Comment: Thanks Michael. That's going to be the plan moving forward, moving to the more common pin-out.

Answer (score 3):

Parametric searches generally suck for linear ICs. Sometimes distributors will list possible substitutions at the bottom of a particular part's page on their website, but don't count on it. Unfortunately, cracking open datasheets and checking is the only consistently successful way I have ever found to accomplish this particular task.

Comment: Thank Matt. I was fearing this was the case.